# Only fluffy waffles always stick

Tags: oil, non-stick, waffle

I have the [Salter Deep Fill XL](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Salter-EK2143-Waffle-Toasted-Sandwich/dp/B01G3B023E/ref=sr_1_3?crid=1AEL41E03KE00&keywords=Deep%2BFill%2BNon-Stick%2B3-in-1%2BSnack%2BMaker&qid=1663927291&refinements=p_89%3ASalter&rnid=1632651031&s=kitchen&sprefix=deep%2Bfill%2Bnon-stick%2B3-in-1%2Bsnack%2Bmaker%2Caps%2C313&sr=1-3&th=1) waffle iron and it has served me very well with this recipe:

- 100ml milk
- 100g self raising flour ([Doves Farm gluten free](https://www.freee-foods.co.uk/products/gluten-and-wheat-free-s-r-white-flour-x-1kg), in my case)
- 1 large egg
- 1tsp vanilla extract
- 20g melted unsalted butter

(Usually made in larger quantities.)

This gets blended for ~30s and poured into the pre-heated waffle iron, without any oil, etc.

8-10 minutes and the waffles typically pull right out without an issue. These waffles are a little too dense, to my taste of late, so...

I have been trying to make them fluffier and changed the recipe to:

- 100ml buttermilk
- 1tbs baking powder
- 100g self raising flour ([Doves Farm gluten free](https://www.freee-foods.co.uk/products/gluten-and-wheat-free-s-r-white-flour-x-1kg), in my case)
- 1 large egg
- 1 egg white
- 1tsp vanilla extract
- 20g melted unsalted butter

(Also usually in multiple quantities.)

The waffle iron is sunflower-oiled heavily and pre-heated.

The egg white is whipped to reasonably firm peak, the wet and dry ingredients are mixed together and then folded into the whipped egg white.

(Yes, I realise the baking powder/whipped egg white is probably unnecessary, but it makes super light waffles.)

I sometimes add a little extra flour.

The problem is this usually sticks very badly to the waffle iron and needs a metal implement to remove it. Even with being pre-oiled.

Adding extra flour seems to improve the situation, but I'm not sure why and is not a guarantee.

What else can I do to help the waffles come away from the iron without sticking and needing a chisel?

Btw, even checking half way through the cooking process usually shows they are stuck before they have even cooked at all.

Comment: You're altering proportions considerably. It would much less of a change to separate the egg, whip the white, and add baking powder to the mix than to leave the flour/butter/etc.  amounts the same and add an egg white. One reference says egg white is ~65% of the egg. Checking halfway through is not generally a good plan, as the crust that forms sticks, then releases as it cooks, normally.